# Cannot retrieve access token for OAuth2 using ajax

Tags: ajax, oauth, oauth-2.0, cross-domain

My problem is that this code is not allowing cross-domain POST. How can I make this work? I must use POST method for retrieving token.

```
 $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: resourceHost,
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        data:{
          'grant-type':'authorization_code',
          'client_id':client_id,
          'client_secret':secret,
          'code':code
        },
        dataType:'json',
        headers:{
          'Api-Key':client_id,
        }
        },function(data){

          console.log(data);

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enable CORS on resourceHost URL to do this, otherwise you will not be able to do it in JavaScript.